# Searching node in tree by using `elem` function - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell and still got some troubles. I'm trying to check if specified element is in my tree, but i want to do this by using the `elem` function - got some errors.

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
              deriving Show

treeMember :: (Eq a) => a -> Tree a -> Bool
treeMember a Empty =  False
treeMember x (Node a l r) 
      | x `elem` [a]  =  True
      | otherwise     =  x `elem` treeMember l || x `elem` treeMember r
```

> ```
> • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Bool’
>       ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>         the type signature for:
>           treeMember :: forall a. Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
> ```

Could anyone give some hint how to fix it? I guess problem is in second guard.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the source of that specific error, but one thing that is certainly wrong (and may fix that error when it is fixed) is that `treeMember l` and `treeMember r` are not lists, so you can't use `elem` with them. I think you meant your second guard to be `treeMember x l || treeMember x r`

Comment: Yay it worked, thanks so much for help :) Simple solution :)

Comment: ``x `elem` [a]`` is the same as `x == a`.

Comment: got it - thanks . will remember about it in the future

Comment: @RobinZigmond FWIW this error message makes no sense because it's not the whole error message, just a prefix of it. jptak, in future please include full error messages. They are written to be useful to diagnose, and do not include extra useless junk, so when you trim them you are removing useful content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `` x `elem` treeMember l `` makes not much sense. Indeed, that would mean that `treeMember l` returns a `Foldable` of elements, so a `Foldable f => f a`. But based on your type signature of `treeMember :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool`, `treeMember l` will return a function `Tree a -> Bool`, and that is not an instance of `Foldable`.

You can here use recursion, so we can call `treeMember x l || treeMember x r`, so then we fix the function to:

```
treeMember :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
treeMember a Empty =  False
treeMember x (Node a l r) = x == a || treeMember x l || treeMember x r
```

or with a helper function:

```
treeMember :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
treeMember x = go
    where go Empty = False
          go (Node a l r) = x == a || go l || go r
```

Note however that you do not *need* to implement a `treeMember` function yourself. Indeed ghc has a [**`DeriveFoldable`** extension [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFoldable), and you can let Haskell derive the `Fodable` instance for `Tree`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Foldable, Show)
```

then you can use [**`elem :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => a -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) on a `Tree a`, object, just like you do that on a list:

```
Prelude> elem 5 (Node 4 (Node 1 Empty Empty) (Node 2 (Node 5 Empty Empty) Empty))
True
Prelude> elem 5 (Node 4 (Node 1 Empty Empty) (Node 2 Empty Empty))
False
```